# How to count number of occurrence consecutive pattern spanning over lines in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, genome

For example, I have a file like this. How can I count the number of occurrences of consecutive N's spanning over lines?

```
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
CACTGCTGTCACCCTCCATGCACCTGCCCACCCTCCAAGGATCNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgtg
gggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGaggcatattgatctgttgttttattttcttacag
ttgtggtgtgtggtgNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

The expected result is `4` because there are `4` groups of `N`

I tried  `grep -Eozc 'N+'`, but the result is 1

If possible, I hope the line number and length of `N` can be shown too

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You might think your question is clear, but I am in doubt too what you want: Do you want to see the linenumber where the string starts? Do you want to count the number of such strings or the length of these strings? When you have more than one string, do you want to see them all? Do you want to count `\n' too in counting the length of a string? Do you also want to see `NNN` when it is not spanning over different lines? Please edit your question to make all this clear. Example output will help a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I had added the expected result for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '$1=$1' FS='' OFS='\n' file | uniq -c | grep -c N
```

or

```
tr -d '\r\n' < file | grep -o 'N*' | grep -c .
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 4):

In plain bash, without using any external command:

```
v=$(<file)X
v=${v//[[:space:]]}
v=${v//N[^N]/ }
v=${v//[^ ]}
echo ${#v}
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

A little long, but straightforward:

```
< tmp.txt \
  tr -d '\n' |  # Strip newlines
  tr -s N |     # Collapse strings of Ns to a single N
  tr -dC N |    # Strip anything that *isn't* an N
  wc -c         # Count the resulting Ns
```

As a one-liner:

```
< tmp.txt tr -d '\n' | tr -s N | tr -dC N | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

### Invoke a Ruby One-Liner from Bash

You can do this as a Ruby one-liner from Bash, whether reading from a file or standard input. For example:

```sh
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.delete("\n").scan(/N+/).count' example.txt
4

$ ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.delete("\n").scan(/N+/).count' <<< "$str"
4
```

The notion is to slurp the whole file, remove all the newlines, and then count the groups of consecutive `N` characters.

*Note: If you want to ignore isolated N's, then just scan for `/N{2,}/` instead. That will only count runs of two or more `N` characters.*

Comment: Thanks, this is also correct! but it would be better if `ruby` don't have to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is in a file called `test.txt`:

1. We read all data from it.
2. Show lines that match our pattern (Starts and ends with `N` and only contains `N`)
3. Count number of lines

So here is the code that do this:

```
cat test.txt | egrep -oe "^N*$" | wc -l
```

Comment: The testdata `here NNN there NNN everywhere NNN.` should give 3 matching patterns.

Comment: @WalterA In his test case, he said he was expecting "4" as output. It means, he expects to match lines that `only`  contain `N`s. If not, please correct me

Comment: I agree that `spanning over lines` could be read as `the whole line` and not `possible continued on the next line`. The example input/output is correct for both interpretations. His own `grep` using `-z` seems to favor `continued next line`, but I see your point.